# write a program that prints out all the the distinct n-tuples of the integers 1,...,m in increasing order without itertools

Tags: python

I know only how to do if the first input is 1 and if the first input is 2, but I don't know how to do the rest.

You can't also use any external modules such as itertools

An n-tuple of integers is a sequence of n integers.

Given a positive integer n and a positive integer m, write a program that prints out all the the distinct n-tuples of the integers 1,...,m in increasing order, as shown in the example.

Sample Input

```
3
2
```

Sample Output

```
1,1,1

1,1,2

1,2,1

1,2,2

2,1,1

2,1,2

2,2,1

2,2,2
```

Sample Input

```
2
3
```

Sample Output

```
1,1

1,2

1,3

2,1

2,2

2,3

3,1

3,2

3,3
```

This is my code so far.

```
def sequence():

    integer = int(input())
    integer_m = int(input())
    array = []

    if integer == 1:
        for i in range(1, integer_m + 1):
            print(i)
    elif integer_m == 1:
        for i in range(integer):
            array.append(integer_m)
        print(*array, sep=",")

sequence()
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to find all possible permutations of a list, while each permutation contains two elements. I recommend looking at the python documentation for `itertools`:

> itertools.permutations(iterable, r=None)
> Return successive r length permutations of elements in the iterable.
> If r is not specified or is None, then r defaults to the length of the iterable and all possible full-length permutations are generated.

The documentation says it's roughly equivalent to:

```python
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
    # permutations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
    # permutations(range(3)) --> 012 021 102 120 201 210
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(n))
    cycles = list(range(n, n-r, -1))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                break
        else:
            return
```

Then you can call it like this: `permutations(some_list, r=2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools` to do the trick -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Here is an exemple that I just tried with several examples and seems to work

```py
from itertools import combinations
print('Enter nbr of item per combinations')
first_nbr = int(input())
print('Enter maximum value')
second_nbr = int(input())
my_list = list(range(1,second_nbr + 1))*first_nbr

# Convert to set then to list to drop duplicates
res = list(set(list(combinations(my_list, first_nbr))))
res.sort()
print(res)
```

Comment: The problem specifies for no `itertools`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `product` from `itertools`

```
import itertools

n = int(input())
m = int(input())
inp = [list(range(1, m + 1))] * n
print (list(itertools.product(*inp)))
```

For input -

```
2 3
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

If you prefer your output format you can change the last line like below

```
for line in itertools.product(*inp):
    print(','.join([str(elem) for elem in line]))
```

Output

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,2
2,3
3,1
3,2
3,3
```

Comment: The problem is that the question does not allow `itertools`. Otherwise good answer.

Comment: @AlanBagel, that information was added later in the question. So, the way out is to implement product